# How to select strings from file via one lines?

Tags: powershell

How to select strings from file via one lines? 
For example my file contains strings
string1
string2
string3
string4

i want get 
string2
string4

I try it this way

```
Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt" | Select-String
```

but i don't know how make this from Select-String method

Comment: Assuming `string1`, `string2` etc. are only examples here, do you mean you want to select only the even numbered lines from the file?

Comment: Yes, i want select only the even numbered lines from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally want to select these two lines, then I guess this is the shortest way to do that:

```
(Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt")[1,3]
```

or

```
Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt" | Select-Object -Index 1,3
```

However, if you mean you want to select only the even numbered lines from the file, you could do this:

```
# return only the even lines (for odd lines, do for ($i = 0; ...)
$text = Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt"; for ($i = 1; $i -lt @($text).Count; $i+=2) { $text[$i] }
```

Or by using `Select-String`

```
# return only the even lines (for odd lines, remove the ! exclamation mark
(Select-String -Path "E:\myfile.txt" -Pattern '.*' | Where-Object {!($_.LineNumber % 2)}).Line
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-Content -Path "~\Desktop\strings.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "string2|string4"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter a stream of objects (strings in this case):

```
Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -match '[24]$'}
# or
Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -like '*[24]'}
# or
Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt" | Where-Object {$_.EndsWith('2') -or $_.EndsWith('4')'}
```

---

If you want only even-numbered lines from the file:

```
Get-Content -Path "E:\myfile.txt" | Where-Object {$_.ReadCount % 2 -eq 0}
```

Comment: thank you, but lines in my file can be random and their number in file is unknown

Comment: @Besha You're gonna have to explain the criteria for selecting the strings then - why was `string2` and `string4` allowed, but not `string1` or `string3`?

Comment: i just want select only the even numbered lines from the file